# How to load data asynchronously using AngularJS with SpringMVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, angularjs

I've new to AngularJS and is stuck wondering about the best way to approach the following situation:

**1.** I need to show rows of data for the last 30 days. (default option)

**How I'm doing it:** When the page loads, the Spring controller puts the list in the model attribute.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/show/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDataPage(ModelMap model) {
        //cropped for brevity
        List<Data> dataList = dataService.getData(fromDate, toDate);
        model.addAttribute("dataList ", dataList );

        return "data-page";
    }
```

And in the JSP I'm using EL tags to loop through the List and show user the data in tabular form

```
<c:forEach var="currentData" items="${dataList}">
    <tr>
        <td>${currentData.name}</td>
        <td>${currentData.address}</td>
        <td>${currentData.email}</td>
        <td>${currentData.phone}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

1. The user has an option to select the date range & depending on the range selected(e.g. today, yesterday, last week, last month, custom range), the data shown should update.

**How I'm doing it:** I'm using Bootstrap-Daterangepicker (https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) to show the markup. It provides me a callback function.

```
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker(options, callback);
```

e.g. `$('#reportrange').daterangepicker(options, function(startDate, endDate){});`

Without AngularJS, this is going to be messy. 
I can call jQuery ajax and then fetch a list, then mess around with the DOM elements from within jQuery. But this is messy.

How can I include AngularJS in this scenario to make my life easier. (and the code a lot less cleaner)
Please help. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use Angular [$http service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http). For even better abstraction, you should go with [$resource service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).

```
var mod = angular.module('my-app', ['ngResource']);

function Controller($scope, $resource) {
  var User = $resource('http://serveraddress/users?from=:from&to=:to', null, {
      getAll: {method: 'JSONP', isArray: true}
    });

  $scope.changeDate = function(fromDate, toDate) {
    $scope.users = User.getAll({from: fromDate, to: toDate});
  };

  $scope.users = User.getAll();
}
```

```
<html ng-app="my-app">
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <input type="text" my-date-picker="changeDate($startDate, $endDate)" />
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td>{{user.name}}</td>
      <td>{{user.address}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</html>
```

To accomodate the DateSelector, you wish to create a directive to encapsulate its requirements. The simplest one would be:

```
mod.directive('myDatePicker', function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            $(element).daterangepicker({}, function (startDate, endDate) {
                scope.$eval(attr.myDatePicker, {$startDate: startDate, $endDate: endDate});
            });
        }
    };
});
```

No need to worry with synchronism. As $resource is based on [promises](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q), it will be automagically bound when data is ready.

Comment: Ok, this sounds feasible. So you mean to say: I don't render the view using EL tags(as shown in the example above) and even in the first time load(for last 30 days range) I use AngularJS to fill up the data for me using handlebars. That's cool. Ok. Now the 2nd part of the problem is: I've got a date range picker library that lets the user select a date range and that should again invoke the Angular Controller somehow, so that the view is updated. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the data must be called again from server with the new parameters or is this a client side filter?

Comment: The data must be fetched again from the server. The range selection library provides a callback function when the range is selected by the user. What about we explicitly call $resource in that function? Will it work? Or do you have a neater solution?

Comment: Wow, this looks neat. Any idea why I'm getting "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
$scope.changeDate(fromDate, toDate) {

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Fixed the example. The right is `$scope.changeDate = function(fromDate...`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25368/discussion-between-littlelebowski-and-caiotoon)

Answer (score 1):

you should do something like this:

SpringMVC Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/load/{page}", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public @ResponseBody String getCars(@PathVariable int page){  
            //remember that toString() has been overridden  
            return cars.getSubList(page*NUM_CARS, (page+1)*NUM_CARS).toString();  
}
```

AngularJS Controller:

```
function carsCtrl($scope, $http){  
    //when the user enters in the site the 3 cars are loaded through SpringMVC  
    //by default AngularJS cars is empty  
    $scope.cars = [];  

    //that is the way for bindding 'click' event to a AngularJS function  
    //javascript cannot know the context, so we give it as a parameter  
    $scope.load = function(context){  
       //Asynchronous request, if you know jQuery, this one works like $.ajax  
       $http({  
              url: context+'/load/'+page,  
              method: "POST",  
              headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}  
       }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
              //data contains the model which is send it by the Spring controller in JSON format  
              //$scope.cars.push is the way to add new cars into $scope.cars array  
              for(i=0; i< data.carList.length; i++)  
                 $scope.cars.push(data.carList[i]);  

              page++; //updating the page  
              page%=5; //our bean contains 15 cars, 3 cars par page = 5 pages, so page 5=0  

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
              alert(status);  
        });             
    }  
}
```

View

```
<!-- Activating AngularJS in the entire document-->  
<html ng-app>  
    <head>  
        <!-- Adding AngularJS and our controller -->  
        <title>Luigi's world MVC bananas</title>  
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">  
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>  
        <script src="js/controller.js"></script><!-- our controller -->  
    </head>  
    <!-- Activating carsCtrl in the body -->  
    <body ng-controller="carsCtrl">  

         <div class="carsFrame">  

               <!-- AngularJS manages cars injection after have loaded the 3 first-->  
               <!-- We use ng-src instead src because src doesn't work in elements generated by AngularJS  -->  
               <div ng-repeat="car in cars" class="carsFrame">  
                   <img ng-src="{{car.src}}"/>  
                   <h1>{{car.name}}</h1>  
               </div>  
         </div>  

         <div id="button_container">  
               <!-- ng-click binds click event with AngularJS' $scope-->  
               <!-- Load function is implemented in the controller -->  
               <!-- As I said in the controller javascript cannot know the context, so we give it as a parameter-->  
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-primary" ng-click="load('${pageContext.request.contextPath}')">3 more...</button>  
         </div>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

The complete example is [here](http://www.luigisworld.com/2013/12/combining-springmvc-with-angularjs.html#more)